# Using function decimal to return only decimal of input as double C++

Tags: c++, decimal

I am on week 3 of C++ & I am so lost. I need to write a program with function decimal - that will return the decimal part of any non negative decimal number sent to it as input. Needs to be clear that it needs to return a double - parameters set at double.

we haven't learned about function decimal yet nor type coercion and trying to teach myself isn't going well.

Comment: `double decimal(double user_input) { ... }` put your code in the braces.

Comment: maybe just subtract the integer part...

Comment: Or you can simply convert it to a string and then remove the part before the decimal and prepend the result with 0

Comment: THANK YOU ALL!  I got it using this #include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    cout << "Please enter a positive number with 2 decimal places \n";
    double a;
    cin >> a;
    cout << (a - floor(a));
    return 0;

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use string conversions:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    float input = 12.123456;
    std::string ip = std::to_string(input);
    ip.erase(ip.begin(), --std::find(ip.begin(), ip.end(), '.'));
    ip.front() = '0';
    std::cout << ip;
    return 0;
}
```

Another way would be simply substracting the floor of the number from itself...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

int main() {
    float input = 12.12;
    std::cout << (input - std::floor(input));
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Check the following example. You can try something like this that is pretty simple.

```
  double num = 23.345;
  int intpart = (int)num;
  double decpart = num - intpart;
  printf("Num = %f, intpart = %d, decpart = %f\n", num, intpart, decpart);
```

Answer (score 0):

Think about the math.

A decimal number is of form a.b where a is the integral part and b the fractional part.

Suppose your input is N (= 1.234) then to extract say frac = .234 you just need to do is

frac = N - floor(N); remember floor(N) is of 1.000.

I think this is of help implement the code.

An example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

int main() {
    float input;
    std::cin >> input;
    std::cout << (input - std::floor(input));
    return 0;    
}
```

or
as a function

```
#include <cmath>
double decimal(const double &N){
    return (N - std::floor(N));
}
```

Comment: so I got it to work like this => cout << "Please enter a positive number with 2 decimal places \n";
       float a;
       cin >> a;
       cout << (a - floor(a));
       return 0;  However, I am supposed to make it a double first.

Comment: what do you mean by make it a double? you are assigning it to a double, instead of cout << (.....) assign it to a double variable, say double frac = (a - floor(a) ) now its already a double. See the function i have written in the answer, that function returns the required answer as a double..

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quit sure that I'm fully understand your question.
Are you having an hard time implementing this function?
If so - think about subtracting the integral part of the number from it, and in that way you will remain with the decimal part only.

Something like: (pseudo code)

```
double a = 10.85
int b = int(a)
return a - b
```